# What's the best starter resource on iOS5 / Xcode 4 programming?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I am working on an iPad (iOS5) project on Xcode 4. I knew I should use split view, and it seems the storyboard in Xcode 4 is good for me to start. But I still have no idea on how to work on it. I don't know how to change from different "pages", or even how to start.

I found most the resource in the Internet are just covered Xcode 3, and Xcode 4 is quiet different to that.

Would anyone please to suggest some good starter resource for Xcode 4??

Thank all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, beside the Apple documentation (which is always the most up-to-date), this link gives a few others : http://maniacdev.com/xcode-4-tutorial-and-guide/ which seem to cover what you're looking for (Storyboard, Interface Builder...)

Comment: Great. Thanks Vinzzz. This is what I need. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Getting Started Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/iphone/)

[Getting Started Ressources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started)

[iOS Development Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html)

[Coding How-Tos](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource%20Types&topic=Coding%20How-Tos)

[Sample Code Collection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)

[Human Interface Guidelines for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: thanks. i modify the question. i want to know how to start with Xcode 4.... i read through all these apple articles already. >.<

Answer (score 1):

As for me the best starter resource for learning iOS5 development was and is iTunes University course ["iPad and iPhone Application Development"](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255), their site with lectures and other resources located [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/)